# Javascript code is not executing with php codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am using some used code in my project

The following code is used to add the product in the wishlist written in view

```
<p class="p"><a<?php  echo "onclick='addtowishlist($product->id)'";  ?>>Add To Wishlist</a></p>
```

The Javascript code for this

```
  function addtowishlist(pid) {   remoteCall("cart/addtowishlist/"+pid,"","loadlist"); }
 function loadlist() { alert(sResponse); }
```

This is my controller naming cart

```
   public function addtowishlist($pID)
    {

    $data=$this->Product_model->addtowishlist($pID);
    echo $data;

    }
```

This is my Model naming Product_model

```
function addtowishlist($ProductID) { echo "Added succesfully";
}
```

This is my ajax for remote call function used in javascript

```
enter code herefunction remoteCall(sUrl, sQueryStr, sCalledBy){

uri = sUrl;
callingFunc = sCalledBy;

xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();

if (xmlHttp==null)
{
    alert ("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
    return;
}
if (xmlHttp) 
{
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateHandler;
    xmlHttp.open("POST", sUrl, true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlHttp.send(sQueryStr);
}   }
```

I only want to show the message written in my controller to displayed when clicked on the Add to wishlist link

Comment: Is `addtowishlist` getting called? Is `removeCall` sending a request to your server? At what point does it fail?

Comment: yes it is getting called even if I write some hard coded value inside alert in addtowishlist then also it gets called

Comment: "xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateHandler;" - where is your stateHandler?

Comment: function stateHandler() 
{
 if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
 {
  
   sResponse = xmlHttp.responseText;
  
   eval(callingFunc+'()');

 }
 return true;
}

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can call the function

```
<p class="p"><a onclick="addtowishlist(<?php echo $product->id; ?>)">Add To Wishlist</a></p>
```

Comment: Your way is same as his way!!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because if the URL, for adding URL to your client side code use `site_url()` function. change this part:

```
 function addtowishlist(pid) {   remoteCall("cart/addtowishlist/"+pid,"","loadlist"); }
 function loadlist() { alert(sResponse); }
```

to:

```
function addtowishlist(pid) {   remoteCall("<?php echo site_url('cart/addtowishlist/'+pid) ?>","","loadlist"); }
 function loadlist() { alert(sResponse); }
```

Of course this part of code should be in PHP file to be able to handle the PHP part.

---

Just for the record the best way for handling these kinds of situation is using JQuery library for AJAX actions and adding the related data to some attribute like `data-href` or other ones.